# Wkhtmltopdf doesn't print images with subdomain

Tags: symfony, subdomain, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using **Wkhtmltopdf** to convert some files to PDF in a **Symfony2** application. In fact, `KnpSnappyBundle` does. This bundle works great, but I have one weird issue:

The web application has two subdomains: `test.domain` and `prod.domain`. The two subdomains have exactly the same content at this moment.
For some reason, the images (converted to PDF) are not printed when using the `prod` subdomain. But if I access the URL directly, the image exists. An example would be:

```
<img src="prod.domain/img/theImage.jpg" /> <!-- This doesn't print the image but the URL is accessible -->
<img src="test.domain/img/theImage.jpg" /> <!-- This works right -->
```

I've finally decided temporally use the `test` subdomain image URL, but it's weird... Any idea?

**Edit:**

**I forgot to say that the `prod` domain use SSL, while `test` doesn't. This seems to be the main problem.**

I've executed from the server:

```
 wkhtmltopdf https://prod.domain test.pdf

Loading pages (1/5)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method               ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Error: Failed loading page https://prod.domain (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)
```

So I've tried again:

```
wkhtmltopdf --ignore-load-errors https://prod.domain test.pdf

Loading pages (1/5)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method               ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Warning: Failed loading page https://prod.domain (ignored)  
Resolving links (2/5)
Counting pages (3/5)                                                      
Printing pages (5/5)                                                      
Done
```

But the new file is bank.

If I use the `test` domain (no SSL):

```
 wkhtmltopdf http://test.domain test.pdf

Loading pages (1/5)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method               ] 21%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Resolving links (2/5)                                              
Counting pages (3/5)                                                      
Printing pages (5/5)                                                      
Done
```

I'm getting the first two errors, but it works and the file is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similiar problem once.

You always have to remember that wkhtmltopdf runs on the server.

That means:

- Different ip than your dev machine (IP restrictions on prod.domain? )
- No session started (Only logged in users can see the file? )
- Doesn't know your hosts file (Maybe you have defined prod.domain in your hosts file? )

Try to **wget** `prod.domain/img/theImage.jpg` when logged in on the server running *wkhtmltopdf*.

Comment: I can do that with `wget --no-check-certificate prod.domain/img/theImage.jpg`, because of the SSL protocol. Think that the file is accessible. The wrong with this is that **images** are not displayed.

Comment: @Manolo " `--no-check-certificate` " Does it work when checking the certificate? I think the server won't accept the certificate an thus wkhtmltopdf can't see them

Comment: And no, it doesn't work if I don't use `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: **wget** doesn't display the image it just downloads it to your current location. You can then transfer it to some place where you can look at it.

Comment: Yes, the image is ok if I use `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: Only then? Ah well then you have your problem. Fix the servers ssl configuration... Someone suggested to install openssl-devel (apt-get install) Idk if that helps, read this: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1516.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Executing `wget prod.domain/img/theImage.jpg` returns: `ERROR: cannot verify prod.domain's certificate, issued by /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.`

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark... Try proxying the image through an action.  Something like this where we first load the file with [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) and then output the image content in the Response:

```
/**
 * @Route("/someroute/image", name="someroute_image")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function imageAction(Request $request)
{
    $imagine = new Imagine();
    $absoluteUrl = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $this->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('/images/logo.png');
    $image = $imagine->open($absoluteUrl);
    $response = new Response($image->get('png'));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    return $response;
}
```

Link to the action in the `src=` attribute of your img tag rather than the image directly.

Answer (score 1):

i think i had the same problem, heres my code (pretty old)

```
protected function prepareForRender($data) {

    $data['app']=array('request' => array('schemeAndHttpHost' => "http://your.host.com"));
    $this->container->enterScope('request');
    $this->container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
    return $data;
}  

public function generatePdf(){

        $data=array();
        $data=$this->prepareForRender($data);

        $html=$this->container->get('templating')->render('someBundle:Report:foo.pdf.html.twig', $data);
        try {
            $pdfString=$this->knp_snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html, array(
                'enable-javascript' => true, 
                'javascript-delay' => 1000, 
                'no-stop-slow-scripts' => true, 
                'no-background' => false, 
                'lowquality' => false,
                'page-height' =>200,
                'page-width'  => 300,
                'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                'images' => true,
                'cookie' => array(),
                'dpi' => 300,
                'image-dpi' => 300,
                'enable-external-links' => true,
                'enable-internal-links' => true
            ));
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->crit($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $pdfString;
}
```

and the img src must be an sbolute url sth like :

```
<img width="405" height="130" src="{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost }}/bundles/akdjaskld/Header.png" alt="">
```

you better make a parameter out of `http://your.host.com` so you have different versions for each stage, maybe youre just missing the `images=>true` option

Comment: Well, in fact that's what I did, but I posted the HTML directly because I tried both. The problem seems to be something related to SSL (https), protocol used by `prod` domain.

Comment: `images=>true` option is set in the configuration file (and works on `test` domain).

Comment: this may help http://oapeon.blogspot.de/2010/06/enabling-support-for-https-in.html

Comment: some comment says `Just install openssl-devel`

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: In fact I installed `libssl-dev`